# Can't deploy functions using google cloud functions-emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have defined the following function in my `index.ts` file:

```
export const stripeCharge = functions.region('europe-west1').database
.ref('/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}')
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    ...
});
```

I want to debug this function, so I am trying to use the Google Cloud Functions Emulator (npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator).

First i run:

```
functions start
```

to start the emulator.

Then I want to deploy the function:

```
functions deploy --trigger-http --timeout 600s stripeCharge
```

This results in the following errors:

```
ERROR: Function load error: Code could not be loaded.
ERROR: Does the file exists? Is there a syntax error in your code?
ERROR: Detailed stack trace: Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail
C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\lib\index.js:14
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.testkey);
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'testkey' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\lib\index.js:14:52)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at [eval]:1:40
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)

ERROR: Error: Failed to deploy function.
    at exec (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\cli\controller.js:126:22)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:288:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

So i think the problem is that it cannot find FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT, which I don't understand since they should be automatically populated according to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

This is at the top of my `index.ts` file:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'firebase-functions';
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';

admin.initializeApp();
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.testkey);
```

I also have a `.runtimeconfig.json` file which contains the following:

```
{
  "stripe": {
    "testkey": "..."
  }
}
```

Finally, here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/sharp": "^0.22.2",
    "@types/stripe": "^6.30.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) provided by the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) in order to test functions written using the Firebase SDKs.  The Cloud emulator (@google-cloud/functions-emulator) will not work.

Unfortunately, you're writing a Realtime Database function, which is currently not supported by the emulator.

Comment: So is there absolutely no way that I can debug my function ?

Comment: You can use this to invoke your function directly, locally.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell

Comment: Thanks. I tried running `firebase functions:shell`, and now it doesn't complain about `FIREBASE_CONFIG` and `GCLOUD_PROJECT` anymore. However, it still cannot find my environment variable `stripe.testkey`... getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'testkey' of undefined`. Please help :-/

Comment: Also, for some reason it's telling me this: `It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.`..

Comment: You now have a different question than the one you first started with, so please post a new question. Your first question is settled (the cloud emulator will not work).